# OnclickListener Crashes when trying to save more than one variable to a file of constants

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences

Alright so I am trying to write this part of the app in which you type in three phone numbers to be saved in a file for later usage. My old setup had a button at the end of each number to save each individual one. This was getting a little redundant and not working to smoothly. I am now trying to clump all three numbers under one save button but every time I hit save it crashes the app.

I do not have access to logcat on my phone for unknown reasons it links to ADB just fine but it wont go anywhere near logcat... I'll post another question about this later.

So here is the code I have right now:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class contacts extends Activity {

EditText num1, num2, num3;
Button saveNums;
Context c = this;
public static String filename = "sharedString";
SharedPreferences prefs;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.contactsettings_layout);
    uiBinder();
    btnManger();
}

public void uiBinder(){
    num1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.num1);
    num2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.num2);
    num3 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.num3);
    saveNums = (Button) findViewById(R.id.saveICEBtn);
}

public void btnManger(){
    saveNums.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //Contact 1 Code
            String num1String = num1.getText().toString();
            Long longNum1 = Long.parseLong(num1String);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
            prefs.edit().putLong(constants.num1, longNum1).commit();

            String num2String = num2.getText().toString();
            Long longNum2 = Long.parseLong(num1String);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor2 = prefs.edit();
            prefs.edit().putLong(constants.num2, longNum2).commit();

            String num3String = num3.getText().toString();
            Long longNum3 = Long.parseLong(num1String);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor3 = prefs.edit();
            prefs.edit().putLong(constants.num3, longNum3).commit();

            Toast.makeText(c, "Contact's have been saved", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .show();
        }
    });
}
}
```

Here is the file they are being sent to:

```
import android.content.SharedPreferences;

public class constants {
public static String PREF_NAME = "sharedString";
public static String ICEnum1 = "num1";
public static String ICEnum2 = "num2";
public static String ICEnum3 = "num3";
SharedPreferences prefs;

}
```

Comment: I would focus first on getting LogCat working.

Comment: check if you can "select" the device from the DDMS view, and mark filter "all messages" for the logcat

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you didnt instantiate your `PreferenceManager`

Instantiate it in your oncreate()

**solution:**

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.contactsettings_layout);
prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this); //instantiate here
uiBinder();
btnManger();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`prefs` variable isn't initialized.

Answer (score 1):

You need to initialize `SharedPreferences` object. like:

```
//in your case only prefs as it has been declared
     prefs = this.getSharedPreferences(
          "com.yourpackagename", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```